# fetching multiple contacts from phone book and display

Tags: android

The problem which i'm facing is I am not able to display the fetched value, as I have used a list view to display the values are not reaching it. This is my code snippet which fetches multiple contacts from phone book. Hope any1 help me solve it.

```
 private void chooseContact() {

    Intent phonebookIntent = new Intent("intent.action.INTERACTION_TOPMENU");
    phonebookIntent.putExtra("additional", "phone-multi");
    phonebookIntent.putExtra("maxRecipientCount", MAX_PICK_CONTACT);
    phonebookIntent.putExtra("FromMMS", true);
    startActivityForResult(phonebookIntent, REQUEST_CODE_PICK_CONTACT);

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == RESULT_PICK_CONTACT) {

            Uri contractData = data.getData();

            ContactRetriever cr = new ContactRetriever(getApplicationContext(), contractData);
            Person p = cr.getPerson();

            if (p == null)

                Toast.makeText(this, "Phone number not found!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            else {
                PersonManager.savePerson(p, getApplicationContext());
                listContacts.setAdapter(new PersonAdapter(this, PersonManager.getSavedPersons(this)));
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

And the Uri value is called and used in next below class

```
    public class ContactRetriever {
    private final String TAG = "ContactRetriever";

    private ContentResolver cr;
    private Context context;

    private Uri contractData;

    private String id;



    public ContactRetriever(Context context,Uri contractData ) {
        this.context = context;
        this.cr = context.getContentResolver();
        this.contractData = contractData;
    }

    public Person getPerson() {
        String name = getName();
        String num = getNumber();

        if (name != null && num != null)
            return new Person(getNumber(), getName());
        else return null;
    }



    private String getNumber() {
        String ret = null;

        Cursor cId = cr.query(contractData, new String[]{ContactsContract.Contacts._ID}, null, null, null);

        if (cId.moveToFirst()){
            id = cId.getString(cId.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
            Log.i(TAG + " IDs: ", id);
        }
        cId.close();

        Cursor cNum = cr.query(contractData, null, null, null, null);

        if (cNum.moveToNext()){
            ret = cNum.getString(cNum.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
            Log.i(ret, TAG + " NUMBERS: ");
        }
        return ret;
    }

    private String getName() {
        String ret = null;

        Cursor c = cr.query(contractData, null, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst())
            ret = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

        c.close();
        Log.i(TAG + "NAMES: ", ret);
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Comment: If i use  Bundle bundle=data.getExtra()  to get the fetched data ...still it throws error in Uri .....The problem is the first code snippet is not linked with the next class of code properly

Comment: Please place your edit back into the question.

Comment: I still haven't fixed the code

Answer (score 1):

Here is my working code for mine

```
//enter code here



private void getAllContacts() {
      List<InviteContactInfo> inviteContactList = new ArrayList();
        InviteContactInfo inviteContactInfo;

        ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");
        if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {

                int hasPhoneNumber = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER)));
                if (hasPhoneNumber > 0) {
                    String id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));

                    inviteContactInfo = new InviteContactInfo();
                    inviteContactInfo.setContactName(name);

                    Cursor phoneCursor = contentResolver.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{id},
                            null);
                    if (phoneCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        String phoneNumber = phoneCursor.getString(phoneCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
                        inviteContactInfo.setContactNumber(phoneNumber);
                    }

                    phoneCursor.close();

                    Cursor emailCursor = contentResolver.query(
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                            null,
                            ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                            new String[]{id}, null);
                    while (emailCursor.moveToNext()) {
                        String emailId = emailCursor.getString(emailCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA));
                    }

                    Bitmap photo =null;


                    try {

                        InputStream   inputStream = ContactsContract.Contacts.openContactPhotoInputStream(getContentResolver(),
                                ContentUris.withAppendedId(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, new Long(id)));

                        if (inputStream != null) {

                            photo = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
                            inviteContactInfo.setContactImage(photo);

                        }
                        else
                        {
                            photo =BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.profilepic);;
                            inviteContactInfo.setContactImage(photo);
                        }

                        assert inputStream != null;
                        inputStream.close();

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    inviteContactList.add(inviteContactInfo);
                }
            }

            InviteContactAdapter contactAdapter = new InviteContactAdapter(getApplicationContext(), inviteContactList);
            recList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
            recList.setAdapter(contactAdapter);
        }
    }
```

Comment: thanks for replying,How do I use it in mine...?? I have two classes ,please try and fix..i am stuck

Comment: the problem with the code which i sent is ...when i run it ..it gets into contact phone book and has a provision to select multiple contacts but does not display...but in case of single contact selection 
        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI);
        startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_PICK_CONTACT);
It works fine.

Comment: in my example code i give number and name accessed in cursor object. please make use of those cursor object to try to get data in your code.

Comment: ContentResolver contentResolver = getContentResolver();
        Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME + " ASC");

Comment: This fucntion get all contact get .But how to select multiple contacts from contact  in android version 10